# How to find number for any range that belongs in list?

Tags: c#

I have a list and an array, I wanted to find each element in the array for any range which belongs to the list.
Here is some code:

```
int[] number = {1, 2, 3, 5};
public List<double> m = new List<double>();
m.add(1);
m.add(1.5);
m.add(2.6);
m.add(4);
m.add(50);
```

For Example :
Get element in array for example 2 and i see where range (between any number in list ) answer that by list ==> 1.5 and 2.6

I want a method which will return this output :

> **`find 1 range is {1} to {1.5} and 2 range is {1.5} to {2.6}`**

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) It might also be worth rephrasing your question as it is a little unclear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I would also like to see what you have tried so far..

Comment: sorry I'm confused. How is {1.5} and {2.6} in range 2?

Comment: find range 1  to 1.5 by list

Comment: 2 content between 1.5 and 2.6

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari I think I just figured that bit out - any two elements of the list form a range. So, 1 and 1.5 create the first range, 1.5 and 2.6 create the second, if simply iterating over the list with `range = currentElement .. currentElement+1`

Comment: @ITDeph It would still be nice to see what you've tried so far :)

Comment: please can you write code .

Comment: Not if you're unwilling to give it a shot yourself. StackOverflow isn't a place to get others to do your work for you.

Comment: @SaladinAkara that makes sense but assuming that, the what would be the relation between this list-range-thing and the array?

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari Given a range defined in the list, identify elements in the array that are within that range. At least, that's what I think he wants.

Comment: get element  in array for example 2 and i see where range (between any number in list ) answer that by list ==> 1.5 and 2.6

Comment: @ITDeph ok so 5 is between 4 and 50 I got it just now. Always ask clear.

Comment: you want to find the two numbers in the array which are higher and lower than the given number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've got what you want.

```
void Main()
{
    var numbers =new [] {1, 2, 3, 5};

    //ordering to make sure that ranges is ascending order
    var orderedRanges = new []{1, 1.5, 2.6, 4, 50}.OrderBy(v => v);

    var valuesInRanges = numbers.Select(number => 
                          FormatValueInRange(
                            number,
                            orderedRanges.Last(range => range <= number ),
                            orderedRanges.First(range => range > number )));

    var result = "Find " + string.Join("and ", valuesInRanges);

    Console.WriteLine (result);
}

private string FormatValueInRange(double val, double lower, double upper)
{
    return string.Format(@"{0} is {{{1}}} to {{{2}}} ", val, lower, upper);
}
```

Prints:

```
Find 1 is {1} to {1.5} and 2 is {1.5} to {2.6} and 3 is {2.6} to {4} and 5 is {4} to {50}
```

Comment: @ITDeph great. Hope I will not receive too many downvotes for answering to you.

Comment: Surely it's better to help new programmers develop problem solving skills than simply provide copy-paste code for them?

Comment: @SaladinAkara So you are making the claim, that he won't learn anything from my answer? Don't forget to downvote all that great answers from kmatyaszek and lazyberezovsky

Comment: No, I'm not making that claim. However, it is surely better to help people develop the skills to solve problems for themselves?

Comment: @SaladinAkara yes, SO is not a site for this, Search for codecademy, topcoder, kaggle and so on. SO is for specific coding problems and specific solutions for them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following logic (in pseudocode, with example numbers):

```
rangeStart = 1
rangeEnd = 7

numberOne = 3.7

if numberOne >= rangestart and numberOne <= rangeEnd
    // number is in range

numberTwo = 12

if numberTwo >= rangestart and numberOne <= rangeEnd
    // number is NOT in range
```

This should point you in the right direction to solve your problem. Give it a try and let us know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
List<double> m = new List<double>();
m.Add(1);
m.Add(1.5);
m.Add(2.6);
m.Add(4);
m.Add(50);

foreach (int n in numbers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (m[i] <= n && m[i + 1] >= n)
                MessageBox.Show(
                    string.Format("{0} is between {1} and {2}",
                    n, m[i], m[i + 1]));
        }
        catch (Exception){ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ.

```
 List<double> m = new List<double>();
   m.Add(1);
   m.Add(1.5);
   m.Add(2.6);
   m.Add(4);
   m.Add(50);

   m.Sort();

   int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
   foreach (var item in numbers)
   {
        double min = m.Where(x => x <= item).Last();
        double max = m.Where(x => x > item).First();

        Console.WriteLine("find {0} range is {1} to {2}", item, min, max);
   }
```